# TypeScript + AngularJS : Directive returning 0 on scope.$eval

Tags: angularjs, typescript, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I created a directive to compile some html then bind it to my element.

Here is the directive

```
    export class BindCompileHtmlDirective implements ng.IDirective {

      restrict = 'A';



      link = (scope: ng.IScope, element: any, attrs: any, ctrl: any) => {
        scope.$watch((scope) => {
            console.log(attrs);
            //Also tried attrs.BindCompileHtmlDirective which returns undefined
            //Tried attrs.$attr.bindCompileHtml also which returns 0 too
            return scope.$eval(attrs.bindCompileHtml);
        }, (value) => {
            console.log(value);
            // In case value is a TrustedValueHolderType, sometimes it
            // needs to be explicitly called into a string in order to
            // get the HTML string.
            element.html(value && value.toString());

            var $phe = this.$compile(element.contents())(scope);
            //element.after($phe);
        });
      }

      constructor(private $compile: any) { 
      }



      static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        const directive = ($compile: any) => new BindCompileHtmlDirective($compile);
        directive.$inject = ['$compile'];
        return directive;
      }

  }

   angular.module('rundeckManager.directives')
      .directive('bindCompileHtml', BindCompileHtmlDirective.factory());
```

and here is the implementation :

```
    <span id="id-of-span" bind-compile-html="{{TabsDomains.domainsLabelHtml}}"></span>
```

The attrs object looks good and contains the value of the string I need to compile, here is the attr object :

[attrsObjectLog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJoiP.png)

But my directive returns 0 as a value instead of the compiled string and I don't understand why.

If someone can explain and help it'd be really helpful.

Comment: have you tried with just `return attrs.bindCompileHtml;`? I might be wrong, but i think `$eval` is for angular expressions, not HTML, maybe as an angular expression this HTML is evaled as 0? The `bindCompileHtml` content seems ready to be placed in the DOM as it is. If you would want to execute what's in the `ng-click` for example, this is where you would have `$eval` (after extracting the content of the ng-click, not on the whole html)

Comment: You were absolutely right ! This worked just fine thank you ! I'll post it as an answer to the question !

Comment: you're welcome, glad to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments of the question, this only needs :
        return attrs.bindCompileHtml

I'm pasting the answer in the comments here  : 
"  $eval is for angular expressions, not HTML, maybe as an angular expression this HTML is evaled as 0? The bindCompileHtml content seems ready to be placed in the DOM as it is "